# Can't log into Tiny Tiny RSS API using Prototype.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, prototypejs

I am attempting to build a reader for Tiny Tiny RSS and am stuck almost at square one. I'm setting the app up to use ajax via prototype.js (1.6.1) and am attempting a simple login to the app to retrieve a key.

Here's what I have so far:

```
new Ajax.Request(Api.BASE_URL, {
  method: "get",
  parameters: {"op": "login", "user": "user", "password": "password"},
  onSuccess: authSuccess,
  onFailure: failure
})
```

Where Api.BASE_URL is defined as "http://tt-rss.example.com/api/"

When I try to log in I get the error response "NOT_LOGGED_IN", which appears to indicate that the api either does not recognize the op call that I am using, or the parameters are wrong, or something.

What is particularly odd is that this should be equivalent to the CURL command:

curl -d '{"op":"login","user":"user","password":"password"}' http://tt-rss.example.com/api/

Which works properly. I get the feeling that I am missing something incredibly simple, but am not sure what it is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the get vs post error, it turns out that the problem was that I was trying to pass a complex json object using the wrong ajax option.

I tested with a simpler function call (isloggedin), so my json object was defined as:

```
parameters: {"op": "isloggedin"},
```

When I used the "parameters" ajax option, the request was sending raw data in the form of:

```
op=isloggedin&_=
```

Which was getting rejected.

On the other hand, the raw data from cURL looked like:

```
{"op":"isloggedin"}
```

Which was working.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494039/posting-a-complex-json-object-using-prototype) put me on the right track. I needed to use "postBody" instead of "parameters" to send the data properly. My final command wound up looking like this:

```
  postBody: '{"op": "isloggedin"}',
```

And it worked. Also, apparently in this case type of quotes does matter. If I used single quotes on the outside, it worked. If I used double quotes on the outside if failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your curl command sends data in a POST request, whereas the Ajax call uses the GET method. According to the tt-rss API documentation, older versions supported both GET and POST, but now [data must be encoded using JSON in HTTP POST data](http://tt-rss.org/redmine/projects/tt-rss/wiki/JsonApiReference).